# saving of row through jquery jtable throws error

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have four fields in my login table (loginid is the primary key and of type varchar)
i have been able to display the records in the jquery jtable. However when i try to create a new record through the modal box of (add new record) using the below code

```
    else if($_GET["action"] == "create")
    {
        $loginid = $_POST["LoginId"];
        $loginpwd = $_POST["LoginPwd"];
        $logintype = $_POST["LoginType"];
        $loginstatus = $_POST["LoginStatus"];
        $sql = "insert into login(LoginId,LoginPwd,LoginType,LoginStatus) values (?,?,?,?);";
        $params = array($loginid,$loginpwd,$logintype,$loginstatus);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params);
        $sql = "select * from login where LoginId='".$_POST["LoginId"]."';";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
        $rows = array();
        $jTableResult = array();
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
//      $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordcount;
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
    }
```

My new records gets inserted in the backend. After the insert, i recieve response due to the ajax call(implying that the create or insertion has been successful), however, the modal dialog box does not close. Also the console shows the following error

```
error on insertion in jquery jtable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LoginId' of undefined     at b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._getKeyValueOfRecord (https://visitorpass.yeshasvee.com/JTable/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js:800:26
```

The loginid is the primary key in my login table. It is of the type string...Can someone confirm why i am getting this error..

Comment: Welcome stack overflow. We cannot help you if you don't show us the code producing the error.

Comment: Hi, i have just added more details to my question. Kindly take a look at it and confirm any possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your json response is incorrect.

The createAction expects a SINGLE Record (Not Records) of the new field. ie. `$jTableResult['Record'] = $row;` You will also need to change your SQL to retrieve the last inserted row.